# 50 Recent Applications on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, launcher

I know that you can [add a recent applications stack to the Dock](http://www.macosxhints.com/article.php?story=20071101055329470), which is fine but very limited. I would like the last 50 or perhaps even 100 apps, sorted by last launch. I do not want to use the keyboard for this (sometimes I don't have one around), so my whole point here is to have it work with just the mouse.

Comment: Probably do this by expanding the OSX cache of recent apps.  you use 100+ apps??

Comment: @memchko, I don't know. Surely more than the 12 or whatever that show up in the recent app stack. I'd say that 30 would be more than enough. If .sh scripts are included, then 100 might be right.

Comment: How useful are these 100 apps without a keyboard?

Comment: Hi Nerdling, thanks for your question. I actually don't need all 50 apps without a keyboard. But I need apps that are among the top 50 without a keyboard. Unfortunately, those apps change a lot (versions, locations, etc.), and by the time I've thought about the change, I've already put the keyboard a few meters away. A top 100 would solve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple ways. In System Preferences -> Appearance, you can set number of recent items. I'm not sure if that affects the stack or just the list under the Apple menu. You can set max 50 for that.

Another way, that I haven't tried, is in [another Mac OS X Hints article](http://www.macosxhints.com/article.php?story=20080319215158929), which says:

> If you followed [this hint](http://www.macosxhints.com/article.php?story=20071101055329470) to create a Recent Items stack in the 10.5 Dock, you know that by default it shows or lists five items.
>
> Now, if you're like me, you'll think it looks silly with a row of three on the top and only two on the bottom. To change it so that there are six items listed, go to the Terminal and type this:
>
> ```
> defaults write com.apple.recentitems ABC -dict MaxAmount nn
> ```
>
> Replace `ABC` with either `Applications` or `Documents`, and replace `nn` with an even number. Your stack (and the Recent Items menu) should now have an even number of entries.

Comment: Hmmm... I did both of these things, not sure whether I needed both, but the thing works, so I'm happy. Thanks again.